# C write serial, redirect to file, terminate

Tags: c, file, serial-port

From C code on an AVR micro controller I am writing text over USART/USB to a PC, where I redirect the text to a file with

```
(stty raw; cat > test.txt) < /dev/ttyUSB0
```

The command blocks until I terminate it using CTRL+C.
What I need is to be able to somehow terminate it from the C code.

I have tried to send EOF and EOT, and to disable the USART transmitter of the controller but all that won't terminate the process.

Even sending some custom character sequence from the code in order to terminate redirection to the file would do for me, but then I guess I need another command and this would be the wrong place to ask this question..?

Comment: Excellent! Using `stty sane` and sending EOT (4) terminates the process - exactly what I was looking for. Thanks - you should make this an answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When reading a serial port in raw mode, the EOF (and other) character(s) is(are) not handled as special control character(s). That's the whole purpose of raw or non-canonical mode: allow all characters to be transmitted/received undisturbed.
You would need to use canonical (text) mode (so that the line discipline would process the control characters).

Instead of `stty raw` try `stty sane`, which enables canonical mode.